# How to set .widgetFamily @Environment variable when NOT in a widget?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I would like to preview my WidgetKit widget in my main app.

The widget lays out differently for `.systemSmall` and `.systemMedium` sizes.

When I set `.environment(\.widgetFamily, .systemSmall)` in the main app I get a build error:

```
Key path value type 'WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, WidgetFamily>' cannot be converted to contextual type 'KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, WidgetFamily>'
```

If I don't set a value, it defaults to `.systemMedium`.

Is there a way to use `.systemSmall`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `widgetFamily` environment key is not setup in the app for obvious reasons, but you can implement it yourself.

First you need to make `WidgetFamily` conform to `EnvironmentKey` like this:

```
extension WidgetFamily: EnvironmentKey {
    public static var defaultValue: WidgetFamily = .systemMedium
}
```

Then you need to add your custom environment key, like this:

```
extension EnvironmentValues {
  var widgetFamily: WidgetFamily {
    get { self[WidgetFamily.self] }
    set { self[WidgetFamily.self] = newValue }
  }
}
```

Now you can use the `.environment()` modifier in the app:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        InterestingWidgetEntryView(entry: .init(date: .init()))
            .environment(\.widgetFamily, .systemSmall)
    }
}
```

This is how I created my widget view:

```
struct InterestingWidgetEntryView : View {
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var family
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var body: some View {
        switch family {
        case .systemSmall:
            Text("Small")
        case .systemMedium:
            Text("Medium")
        case .systemLarge:
            Text("Large")
        default:
            Text("Some other WidgetFamily in the future.")
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Widget view loaded in app using correct family]

Keep in mind that the widget view will not have the widget size, you'll have to calculate that yourself.

Comment: thanks for this, looks great! i'll give it a go next early week :)

Comment: Happy to help!!